# Yii2 error swift mail

Tags: yii2, swiftmailer

Good Morning,

I'm using Swift Mailer for applications, but I found that it returns an error code.

ReflectionException

Class Swift_Mime_ContentEncoder_QpContentEncoderProxy does not exist

this is the link: http://demonagency.com/legno/web/site/about

this is a portion code

```
Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
->setFrom('info@jd.com')
->setTo('prove@jd.com')
->setSubject('Prova jd')
->setTextBody('Testo Prova')
->setHtmlBody('<b>HTML content</b>')
->send();
```

>
Any idea?

Comment: Check if QpContentEncoderProxy.php class exists in folder ..\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Mime\ContentEncoder\ . If not, I assume your vendor folder is corrupted, and you should update composer

Comment: Thanks to you I solved, you saved my life :)

Comment: You are welcome =)